# How to not fry a Raspberry PI while wiring it to a relatively high voltage pin of a frequency inverter?

Tags: digital-logic, raspberry-pi, inverter, output

I'm working with a frequency inverter brand Metaltex type IF20 and a Raspberry PI. With the RPI I'm going to get some  digital readings using one of its GPIOs, and for that I'll wire it to a digital output pin from the inverter, which the manual says is a transistor output, something like that.

I know the AC source symbol is kind of wrong in the diagram, but anyways the diagram bellow is what I was thinking to do.

[image]

My doubt is about something I read on the inverter's manual, which says MCM is a common wire and M01 corresponds to an output of "MAX 48VCC/50mA". Raspberry only has 3.3V and 5V pins, so if I get a 48V signal I'll damage the board big time.

Does anyone know how the M01 pins and MCM work?

I don't know if I might need a separate DC source between the RPI and the inverter.

Comment: By "transistor input", do you/the manual mean something like an *open-collector* or *open-drain* output? Having a bit more context from the manual would be helpful. Further details about how these two systems share a ground (or don't, in case it's an optoisolated output) would also be helpful to know.

Comment: "something like that"? You need to provide more information.

Comment: Could you use the RS485 interface instead? You can get ready-made RS485 hats for the RPi.

Comment: @nanofarad the M01 and MCM terminals are optocoupled, I think it may be an open-collector circuit and I'm not sure about whether I should wire the RPI ground pin to the MCM pin (for me that's when they would share a ground)

Comment: @ALANVINICIUSBORATO But if it is an optocoupler output where the emitter is not grounded then they would not share a ground.

Comment: @AndrewMorton yeah but the ones I'd seem were kind of expensive and I've never worked with tranceivers (to convert serial to RS485 and vice versa) which would be also an option

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet isn't much help:

[image]
Source: https://www.metaltex.com.br/assets/produtos/pdf/m_if20.pdf

It looks like an opto isolator (but they have a bar across the pins, whatever that means). If it is an optoisolator with a transistor output, you could connect it in a variety of ways such as this:

[image]
Source: http://lednique.com/tag/optocoupler/ (with edits)

You would provide the +5V or +3.3V to the M01 pin and the MCM pin would need a resistor to ground (another option is a high side configuration).

I'd either contact the manufacturer and ask them what they mean or check the M01 and MCM pins either with a meter or revere engineer the PCB (trace back the traces to the optocoupler and see if they are connected to anything but the terminals)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I'll really contact the manufacturer also

Comment: I would strongly recommend against wiring the GPIO connector unprotected directly on a cable near a variable frequency converter. Aside from the noise, it may even kill the poor broadcom.

Comment: @Jeroen3 and your reason for this is? The optoisolator might fail?

Comment: Did you ever wire IO's near a VFD on a product that wasn't entirely up to the iso standards? It sees ghost signals and spontaneously reboots when you start braking with the vfd. You need to protect the input and have sufficient trigger levels. Hence why the little schematic above already indicated you should used shielded cable. The opto in the drive will not fail no...

Comment: So it should be alright if I wire the IO to the inverter with shielded cable?

Comment: I would think so, assuming the optoisolator is sufficient most provide isolation against hundreds or thousands of volts.